# Byte streams in java

Tags: java, file-io, unicode, character-encoding, fileoutputstream

Can we write Unicode Data in a File with ByteStreams?
My code is:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String str = "Русский язык ";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file path");
    fos.write(str.getBytes());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

Here i am using a byte stream to write unicode data, but it is writing properly.I am new to java but i have read that byte streams do not support unicode characters. So, why does it is working in this case?

Comment: @Andrew Sure sir, i will take care, from now onwards.

Comment: The Unicode stuff is dealt with in the `getBytes()` call, though you should really pass it an explicit charset like UTF-8.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman  But here i am not mentioning UTF-8, but it is taking and how its working, i am bothered?

Comment: @Andrew I will do it right away

Comment: `string.getBytes()` [uses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) the platform [default charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()).

Comment: @Louis Wasserman : Thanks for the usefull reply.I ckecked the default encoding , it is UTF-8, but i am using a byte stream, how it can work with a unicode character? i am not getting?

Comment: *"will do it right away"*  Good call.  Glad you got an answer to this one.  :)

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson , i need proper explanation,i am not getting, i need to understand byte and character streams properly, no site is much helpful, can u suggest some and give some explanation.

Comment: A charset like UTF-8 takes characters (in this case, Unicode characters) and converts them to and from byte sequences.  All that's happening here is that the Unicode characters are getting written, in the UTF-8 charset, to a byte sequence in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have read that byte streams do not support unicode characters.

Either you have used a bad source of information or you have probably misunderstood something. Byte streams support bytes. Therefore byte streams support *anything* that can be represented in bytes. Videos, text, pictures, music... If byte stream doesn't support it, it cannot be used in a digital computer at all.

The trick to represent those things in what is a simply a sequence of 1 and 0's, is to use agreed upon rules. You would encode your text according to certain rules, and then the receiver can decode it back using the same rules.

`"Русский язык"` can be represented as bytes in any encoding that supports cyrillic characters. In any of the encodings of unicode: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32; Windows-1251, KOI8-R, KOI8-U, ISO-8859-5...

That doesn't mean these encodings are compatible with each other. They are all incompatible when it comes to encoding Cyrillic script, so text encoded in one the encodings, must strictly be decoded in that encoding.

`.getBytes()` uses the platform default encoding, which happened to be a one that supported Cyrillic script. You might believe it's UTF-8 but if you are on Windows, it's far more likely to be Cp1251. Don't fall into trap that just because you used "unicode characters", that your files are physically encoded in an UTF encoding. That will lead to encoding problems.

So always be explicit about encoding, so that your program works the same on any platform and so that you always know what encoding the files your program created are in. With your code, you could have done this:

```
String str = "Русский язык ";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file path");
fos.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Or as suggested by the other answer:

```
String str = "Русский язык ";
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("file path"), "UTF-8"
);
osw.write(str);
osw.flush();
osw.close();
```

These are technically exactly the same; text is being converted to bytes according to UTF-8 rules.

Comment: This is really a nice answer, appriciate it,What if i used some Hindi characters, will it also be  represented as bytes in any encoding that supports cyrillic characters?

Comment: @RiteshKaushik nope, you need encoding that supports Devanagari characters. But unicode includes all characters used on the planet, so you are safe with UTF-8

Comment: @ Esailija: Thnx for reply pa, but if the text is Hindi and i am not specifying UTF-8 any where in my code, it will use default encoding which is ISO 8859-1 in my case, then how it is working in this case,even if i am using "FileOutputStream" to write hindi characters to a text file(without using UTF-8), it is writing correctly?

Comment: @RiteshKaushik then the default encoding wasn't ISO-8859-1. Try the outputstream with `Charset enc = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");` You should see `????? ????`, nothing, or get an error.

Comment: I am using "Charset.defaultCharset()" which is printing ISO-8859-1. Also "Charset enc = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");" is printing "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: @RiteshKaushik that's not my point, try writing Hindi text with ISO-8859-1 specified and see it will not work: `byte[] a = "Русский язык ".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");` will be full of `0x3f`, which is `?`. Because it worked for you, it only means that `ISO-8859-1` was not the charset that was used.

Comment: Yes pa u r right, my text file encoding is UTF-8, but default character encoding in eclipse IDE is ISO-8859-1? How this is working is my doubt?

Comment: @RiteshKaushik It's working because UTF-8 was used by default to write the file... but you cannot rely on this at all if you want your code to be cross platform.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
    
public class SynchronizedByteStream {
    
    public synchronized byte[] getObjectAsByteStream(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            
        // Write the object to the byte stream
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
            
        // Get the byte stream as a byte array
        byte[] byteStream = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    
        // Close the streams
        objectOutputStream.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            
        return byteStream;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SynchronizedByteStream synchronizedByteStream = new SynchronizedByteStream();
    
        // Example object
        String exampleObject = "Hello, World!";
            
        // Get the byte stream from the object
        byte[] byteStream = synchronizedByteStream.getObjectAsByteStream(exampleObject);
    
        // Print the byte stream
        System.out.println("Byte Stream: " + new String(byteStream));
    }
}
```